# How to get the rows that some of the users did event1 but did not do event2?

Tags: mysql, sql

In this query I am trying to find users who visited the page, but did not see the content. All I can find was this query, but this query is slow so much. Is there any way in your mind that I can find a better solution? Thank you!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT pl.user_id FROM visited_logs vl 
    LEFT JOIN seen_logs sl ON sl.user_id = vl.user_id 
    WHERE vl.camp_id IN ('33') AND vl.camp_type = 0 
    AND sl.camp_id IS NULL 
  ) as joined ON joined.user_id = u.id 
  WHERE u.status = 'alive'
) derp
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT u.id
      FROM users u INNER JOIN
           (SELECT pl.user_id
            FROM visited_logs vl LEFT JOIN
                 seen_logs sl
                 ON sl.user_id = vl.user_id 
            WHERE vl.camp_id IN ('33') AND vl.camp_type = 0 AND
                  sl.camp_id IS NULL 
           ) joined
           ON joined.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE u.status = 'alive'
     ) derp;
```

I would suggest writing this:

```
select count(*)
from users u
where u.status = 'alive' and
      exists (select 1
              from visited_logs vl
              where vl.user_id = u.id and
                    vl.camp_id = 33 and
                    vl.camp_type = 0
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from seen_logs sl
                  where sl.user_id = u.id  -- do you want camp_id here too?
                 );
```

I think you are missing a comparison to `sl.camp_id`.

For this query, you want indexes on `visited_logs(user_id, camp_type, camp_id)` and `seen_logs(user_id, camp_id)`.

Comment: The project I am working on has a segmentation module and the module's sql code starts with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT u.id FROM users u` as always, Thank you for the answer, I will try to make it work now.

Comment: Hi Gordon, user alive query takes all the alive users which takes approx 1_000_000 and scans results from that portion, I added different indexes but could not manage to drop that portion, which indexes should I add ? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mike . . . Can you ask another question, with the full query and execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure, but try this solution, hope it helps:

```
select count(*)
from users u 
join visited_logs vl on vl.user_id = u.id 
     and u.status = 'alive' 
     and vl.camp_id = 33 
     and vl.camp_type = 0 
join seen_logs sl on sl.user_id = vl.user_id
     and sl.camp_id is null
```